# How can I use ticks for Word 2003 form check boxes instead of crosses?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, forms

I've created a form using Word 2007 and saved it in Word 2003 format. It works well, but I don't like the way that the check box presents itself as being checked.

Currently when I click the check box, a cross is shown in it. I want to change it to something else - preferably a tick, or even a completely filled box will do.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using **Legacy Form Check box's**, that's the reason you are seeing **cross mark** while it is checked.

If you use **ActiveX Controls Check box** then you can see **Tick mark** while it is checked.